# What is the best skim coating for polystyrene sheets?

Tags: insulation, ceiling

My log hut is extremely hot, I have glued polystyrene sheets to the ceiling and would like to skim to create a clean finished off appearance. The sheets are the pressed pellets type (not isoboard)

can normal gypsum/ rhinolite/ plaster work? Any advice would help.

Comment: I think at that point you would need something textured to give the plaster something to hold on to. Self adhesive fiberglass tape might help, but what's to keep that adhering to the polystyrene? I'm not sure of the answer, but I think something like that would be a good direction.

Comment: The adhesive on mesh drywall tape is very weak - it just holds it in place until the "mud" (joint compound) is applied (if you don't wait too long.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach (probably to the logs with long screws) metal lath

[image: metal lath for plaster]

for the plaster to stick to, sure. If you only attach that to the foam, I kinda doubt it will stay, and without the lath I doubt the plaster will stay put long-term. Of course you could also just put drywall/plasterboard sheets up, again with screws long enough to hit wood (and adhesive, if you like.)

Comment: Agree that nothing will stick to the polystyrene long term.  I like this solution.